# Cannont access localhost websites after creating virtual host

Tags: apache

I have created a virtualhost for one of my localhost websites:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysite 
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite/public
  <Directory /var/www/html/mysite/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All 
    allow from all 
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I can't access other local websites anymore. for example when I go to `localhost/anotherwwebite` I get redirected to mysite.

Comment: Do you also have a virtual host for your other local websites?

Comment: From httpd.conf:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container. The first VirtualHost section is used for requests without a known server name.

Answer (score 18):

To get it work please follow these steps:

1. Enable Virtual host configuration file from ***httpd.conf*** *<sup>1</sup>*

   un comment (remove `#` from start)  below entry

   #Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
2. Configure ***httpd-vhost.conf*** *<sup>2</sup>*

   Here you have to write **two** configurations set one for localhost and one for virtual host.

   put following

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
> ServerAdmin localhost.admin
> DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www"  >> For UBUNTU /opt/lampp/htdocs/
> ServerName localhost
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

(prior to virtual host)

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
> ServerAdmin pimcore.test
> DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\pimcore-latest"
> ServerName pimcore.test
> ErrorLog "logs/pimcore.test.log"
> CustomLog "logs/pimcore.test.log" common
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

3. and following entries in system **hosts** *<sup>3</sup>*

   127.0.0.1       localhost

   127.0.0.1       pimcore.test

of course these will vary depends of Your virtual server names.

---

1 :  *C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf\**httpd.conf*** OR */opt/lampp/etc/**httpd.conf***

2 :  *C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf\**extra\httpd-vhosts.conf*** OR 
     */opt/lampp/etc/**extra/httpd-vhosts.conf***

3 : *C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts:* OR */etc/hosts*

Regards

Comment: You are gem.This is straight forward and simple.Why this isn't accepted yet?

Comment: **Worked like a charm**. After searching for 5 hours... finally got something that worked for me! Thanks a ton.

Comment: Thank you! Before, my localhost is redirecting me to the project I set in virtual host. I just added the step no.2 and my localhost works again.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, not on local host however, I do not have a httpd.conf file what would the solution look like on Ubuntu 16.4 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add some line in

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host

add this line

127.0.0.1  yoursitename

for example
let ur site name is stack.overflow 
127.0.0.1    stack.overflow

in ur browser you can you stack.overflow instead of localhost

so that you can now use yoursitename instead of localhost

hope this help....